# Odoo12 Error XML When upgrade module or install module

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

I got an error `lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document, line 13, column 9` in Odoo 12, When I upgraded each module or install new module. I cannot working. T_T

I'm not sure my code is wrong or any thing else, But i try to debug variable `view_arch` i found the XML  start is missing.

Help me please, Thank you for advance.

file view.xml:

```
<record id="view_company_form_inherit_social_media" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.company.form.inherit.social.media</field>
    <field name="model">res.company</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_company_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//group[@name='social_media']" position="replace">
            <group string="Social Media" name="social_media">
                <field name="social_twitter"/>
                <field name="social_facebook"/>
                <field name="social_github"/>
                <field name="social_linkedin"/>
                <field name="social_youtube"/>
                <field name="social_googleplus"/>
                <field name="social_instagram"/>
            </group>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

XML Parser when install or upgrade:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

        <xpath expr="//group[@name=\'social_media\']" position="replace">
            <group string="Social Media" name="social_media">
                <field name="social_twitter"/>
                <field name="social_facebook"/>
                <field name="social_github"/>
                <field name="social_linkedin"/>
                <field name="social_youtube"/>
                <field name="social_googleplus"/>
                <field name="social_instagram"/>
                
            </group>
        </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
    
</odoo>
```

This error:

```
Error:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 1111, in _validate_fields
    check(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 346, in _check_xml
    view_arch = etree.fromstring(view.arch.encode('utf-8'))
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3213, in lxml.etree.fromstring
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1876, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1764, in lxml.etree._parseDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1126, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 600, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 710, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 639, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
  File "<string>", line 13
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document, line 13, column 9

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 757, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 662, in _tag_record
    record = model.with_context(rec_context)._load_records([data], self.mode == 'update')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 3841, in _load_records
    records = self._load_records_create([data['values'] for data in to_create])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 3755, in _load_records_create
    return self.create(values)
  File "<decorator-gen-32>", line 2, in create
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 452, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 431, in create
    return super(View, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in create
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 452, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 3572, in create
    fields[0].determine_inverse(batch_recs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 1114, in determine_inverse
    getattr(records, self.inverse)()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 275, in _inverse_arch
    view.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 447, in write
    return super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 3287, in write
    self._write(store_vals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 3433, in _write
    self._validate_fields(vals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 1115, in _validate_fields
    raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (_("Error while validating constraint"), tools.ustr(e)))
odoo.exceptions.ValidationError: ('Error while validating constraint\n\nExtra content at the end of the document, line 13, column 9', None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 654, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 312, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 696, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 344, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 337, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 939, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 517, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 966, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 954, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 749, in call_kw
    return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 736, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-61>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 74, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 445, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 561, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 421, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 313, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 222, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package, report=report)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 68, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 801, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 864, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 763, in parse
    exc_info[2]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 86, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 757, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 662, in _tag_record
    record = model.with_context(rec_context)._load_records([data], self.mode == 'update')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 3841, in _load_records
    records = self._load_records_create([data['values'] for data in to_create])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 3755, in _load_records_create
    return self.create(values)
  File "<decorator-gen-32>", line 2, in create
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 452, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 431, in create
    return super(View, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in create
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 452, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 3572, in create
    fields[0].determine_inverse(batch_recs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 1114, in determine_inverse
    getattr(records, self.inverse)()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 275, in _inverse_arch
    view.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 447, in write
    return super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 3287, in write
    self._write(store_vals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 3433, in _write
    self._validate_fields(vals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 1115, in _validate_fields
    raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (_("Error while validating constraint"), tools.ustr(e)))
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Error while validating constraint

Extra content at the end of the document, line 13, column 9
None" while parsing /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/social_media/views/res_company_views.xml:4, near
<record id="view_company_form_inherit_social_media" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">res.company.form.inherit.social.media</field>
        <field name="model">res.company</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_company_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//group[@name='social_media']" position="replace">
                <group string="Social Media" name="social_media">
                    <field name="social_twitter"/>
                    <field name="social_facebook"/>
                    <field name="social_github"/>
                    <field name="social_linkedin"/>
                    <field name="social_youtube"/>
                    <field name="social_googleplus"/>
                    <field name="social_instagram"/>
                </group>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>

</odoo>
```

Comment: try to add `<odoo></odoo>` tag before and after record tag

Comment: I solve it. i try to upgrade version of lxml package.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<odoo>` tag as like below

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="view_company_form_inherit_social_media" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">res.company.form.inherit.social.media</field>
        <field name="model">res.company</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_company_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//group[@name='social_media']" position="replace">
                <group string="Social Media" name="social_media">
                    <field name="social_twitter"/>
                    <field name="social_facebook"/>
                    <field name="social_github"/>
                    <field name="social_linkedin"/>
                    <field name="social_youtube"/>
                    <field name="social_googleplus"/>
                    <field name="social_instagram"/>
                </group>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should at least mention the missing `<odoo>` tag at the beginning to get upvotes.